# Cannot detect Sony Xperia in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sony-xperia

I  am totally new at testing apps on devices, especially the Sony Xperia. I am testing apps using the Android emulator, but I have now a Sony Xperia. First I have connected the device to the laptop via USB. But the laptop couldn't detect my phone. Is a driver necessary for Eclipse to detect the phone?

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11974943/704374 this will help you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Download the correct driver for your phone, make sure your phone has enabled USB debugging and then connect it to proceed with the install.

Download drivers from:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

Comment: +1. I downloaded driver from there and followed instruction [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14083512/593709) to update the drive. this enabled the eclipse to detect my Xperia S. thanks.

Comment: Windows has determined your driver is up to date is what I get. Still cannot be seen in Eclipse.

Comment: @AndrewS Had the same problem. I solved it by enabling *Mass storage mode (MSC)* as described by Damir. The phone then appeared under "Other devices" instead, and installing the driver worked this time!

Comment: I found it hard to get the right drivers for my xperia, so downloaded the PC companion which downloads the right drivers for you - http://support.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/

Answer (score 29):

Even though this question was posted long time ago, I didn't find 100% correct answer from previous replies. Most of replies are useful, but here is one final step for debugging apps on Sony Xperia devices. 
My Sony Xperia T has not been visible in Eclipse even though I installed PC Companion and in mobile phone, I set developers options debugging mode! 
 
**Xperia** has very strange option:
*Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > USB connection mode*
and select **Mass storage mode (MSC)**. 
Note that the USB cable must be unplugged to change this option.
By default, Media transfer mode (MTP) was selected. If MTP is selected even little bug is shown in notification bar debugging is not possible!

Comment: Great, thanks; this also worked on my Sony Xperia Tablet Z -- I would never have found that option otherwise :-)

Comment: I have a Sony Xperia M and this is been the solution to my problem. With no PC Companion and MSC usb connection mode the android device manage on my Eclipse got to recognize my phone. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from the usual stuff: installing google usb drivers, PC companion, enabling debugging , allowing apps from unknown sources, etc. Enabling MASS STORAGE worked!! The Sad part was that I couldn't listen to the MP3s on my phone while it was hooked to eclipse. Fortunately, whe you activate MASS Storage for the first time the phone asks you to include your computer in the Trusted Devices List. Once you do so, you can then put it back to Media Transfer Mode and enjoy Eclipse connection while listening to MP3s at the same time!! Happy Coding.

Answer (score 10):

These were my steps to solve the problem:

On SONY XPERIA Z

- Enable USB debugging (http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up)
- Settings > Developer > USB-Debugging = Enabled
- Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > USB connection mode = MSC
- Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > Install software = Disabled (!!!)

On Windows7

- Google USB drivers were already installed for another device
- Download XPERIA drivers from: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/
- Connect XPERIA via USB
- Device manager > Unknown device > Install driver from downloaded file

Comment: I dont see this option: Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > USB connection mode = MSC - it only gives me one option in the USB Connectivity Menu and that's "Install PC Companion" and of course that doesn't work either ;) any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to enable usb debugging in the phone setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, eclipse needs drivers. You need to install drivers for the phone, and then restart eclipse. You then need to add the xperia through the device manager in eclipse.

Are you running windows??

Comment: yes, I am using windows, but i already install google usb driver. Is google usb driver doesnot work for this?

Comment: No you need the drivers for the Xperia - and don't forget to turn on phone debugging. Check here http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/search-downloads/driver

Answer (score 0):

1. Start eclipse
2. open the android SDK manager,it will load the repository.
3. select the package for sony and download it.
4. restart eclipse,and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Install PC Companion here:
http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem connecting a Sony Xperia Tipo to Eclipse for android debugging. I went through all the steps already recommended (installing sony drivers, USB debugging on, etc), but was still getting a "driver not found" error when I connected the Tipo to my PC with USB debug switched on.

I fixed the problem starting with the driver install instructions for a Sony Tablet, http://www.kb.sony.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=C1024692&fes=true

Then I looked through Windows event viewer to find the find the details of the previous driver install failures, which gave me the correct device ID string for the Tipo. I added that to the end of the [Google.NTx86] section of android_winsub.inf, following the same pattern as for the Sony Tablet. It now contains this:

```
[Google.NTx86] 
;SONY Sony Tipo
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0FCE&PID_5170&MI_01
```

Finally I reconnected the Tipo to my PC, went for the manual driver search options during driver install, pointed it to the Google USB driver directory, and it installed the Google drivers successfully. Now Eclipse is connecting to the Tipo and I can test and debug my app.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION  ! : I had that problem with the detection of the SONY XPERIA Z tablet only with Eclipse and did everything in the book to connect it without success :

Checked that the Sony USB driver was updated on the PC,
enabled USB debugging in the developpers options,
tried the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP),
tried the Mass Storage Configuration (MSC),

still the Eclipse command Run responded with a 'No compatible device found" message

until I downloaded the Google USB driver in the SDK manager and the DEVICE WAS AT LAST DETECTED.
This is all the more so strange that the Google Driver is introduced as dedicated to Nexus tablets only ! 
So if this can help ....

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed this problem recently. Here's the steps you should try as follows:

- enable usb debugging
- change to mass storage device
- reset DDMS - adb
- install driver

Then in eclipse it should show up as an Android device :)

Answer (score 0):

solution for sony Mobile usb driver for Window 7 
After googling and more time spend on this we find the solution Sony tipo & Sony M mobile are detecting by eclipse .
Steps are 1.install the latest sony companion 
2- go to settings>>xperia>> connectivity>>USB connectivity mode>>MTP 
3- restart eclipse and run your project Android Device Chooser show your device

donot forgot to check the usb debugging

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more general to not finding your device. But if you have dead ADB processes running, you might have to kill them (and start a new one) in order to pick your device.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works when combining Damir's & Michell Bak's answers.

First need to change device form **MTP** mode to **MSC** mode as [Damir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053720/cannot-detect-sony-xperia-in-eclipse/15543848#15543848) mentioned, then **download and install driver** to your PC as [Michell Bak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12053939/4570366) mentioned.

Most new Sony device default setting USB connection mode to MTP and the setting location is different from other android devices. Besides, driver can not install automatically and need to download form official site.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to debug using Sony Xperia :
**Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > USB connection mode**
and select ***Mass storage mode (MSC)***. 
The USB cable must be unplugged to change this option. 
By default, Media transfer mode (MTP) was selected.
Untick "Install software"

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my Xperia Z3+ (android 5.02) with Android studio 1.3.
I installed new drivers and XPeria Companion but it didn't help. 
However after I enabled hotspot via USB it started to work. Don't know if all of these was needed of if it was only the last one. Anyway I did
1. Settings->More...->Internetsharing hotspot->USB-sharing to on. 
2. In the pop-up accept USB debugging.