# Eclipse not detecting Sony Ericsson Xperia for debugging?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My eclipse is not detecting my phone . I want to directly run my application in my phone . My phone has Android Version 4.0.4. Whenever i connect my phone with my Laptop it shows unknown in device's list .

Comment: is USB debugging enabled?

Comment: Yes it is enabled . My colleague is using Mint Version of Linux & it's working on his Laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade your Ubuntu & there is a chance that then your Phone will be working fine with Eclipse .

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:-

- Enable USB Debugging (Settings --> Security  --> Developer Option -->
  Enable USB Debugging)
- If still doesn't work, try to reset the `adb` (DDMS Perspective --> Devices Tab --> Small Triangle on right side(Last option) --> Reset adb)

Answer (score 1):

Set this option in your mobile device before plug in USB cable:
*Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > USB connection mode* > **Mass storage mode (MSC)**
See my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15543848/419446)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows most likely you should reinstall drivers, I faced this type of ussue many times and every time there was a problem with drivers.

Comment: @ TpoM6oH which drivers ? I am using Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 0):

2 Steps 
a) try downloading gooogle driver from within eclipse
b) using the downloaded driver

Both steps can be found [here](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php)
Of course you have to unlock sony as well. I followed R.J comment for that and worked.