# Cant attach sony acro s phone to adb on windows 7

Tags: android

Read a lot about how to do this including all simple advices like "enable debug on phone" or "use vendor driver" etc.

1. Ask people not faced with the problem not post here.
2. Vendor driver from http://www.sonymobile.com/ is not in form of dll, so I cant switch to it directly. It offers PC Companion that doesnt help me with adb.
3. When I use google usb driver system tells me it cant be used.
4. When I use http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-acro-s-driver-for-ics/ it does not help me too.
5. Some people [Cannot detect Sony Xperia in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053720/cannot-detect-sony-xperia-in-eclipse/15657558#15657558) would say they can edit google usb driver files to make it runnable but it is too difficult for me in this case - windows 7 has verbose event log to find smth relevant in it.(In the case of looking for correct device ID string during driver installing).

My request is to post here real helpful advice and better go to skype alexinspire where I can share my machine with team viewer to do thigs clear. Im really in trouble. Think you can understand me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I hope I'm not too late at the party.. Follow these steps, that worked for me:

Attach your device, Go to Device Manager, there in Other Devices you've your mobile device(uninstalled device) Right Click to device
-> select Properties  goto Details-> Property -> Select Hardware ID, copy it....

Now in your android sdk folder search a file name "android_winusb.inf"
or directly go to **\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf**
Open this file in notepad**(with administrator rights)** and add your hardware id in this manner

```
;Sony Acro S
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, "enter_your_device_Hardware_ID"(without quotes)
```

[image]

Now go back to your device driver installation, and search from file in this way
**Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver**

It will give you warning, install it anyway.. 
You're finished. It should appear in your eclipse now.

**Note: This solution worked for me, I'm not responsible for any loss that occur to your data or phone.**

Comment: @traninho Make sure your sdk is Up-to-date.

Comment: sorry, but no luck