# adb can't detect Sony Xperia s although I installed driver

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I want to use my Xperia S for debugging, so I followed the [OEM USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) instructions step by step but still not work, I didn't find "Android Composite ADB Interface" to update driver as it explained. and when I call adb devices my device didn't appear in the list.

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796900/cant-attach-sony-acro-s-phone-to-adb-on-windows-7/15815420#15815420

Comment: Thanks Numair,I tried it but still not working, in my case the driver installed successfully but not detected for debugging.

Comment: Solved it for Xperia Z Ultra, By using [this driver download](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-z-ultra-c6833-c6806-c6843-driver/), & following the instructions from http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/2/ to update the driver.

Answer (score 29):

I found out that you must put your phone in Mass Storage mode, as default is MTP mode. As simple as that @#! And I spent hours trying all sorts of things reading posts.

Settings / Xperia / USB Connectivity / USB Connection Mode and select MASS Storage, not MTP. I did uncheck Install PC Companion. It work right away. No need to Update drivers, no need to change the android_winusb.inf. You may need to kill adb.exe before trying again adb devices.

That was it for me :)

Comment: I wish that somewhere (adb, PC, phone, ...) something could have told me this long time ago. It's really frustrating trying to connect to a phone in MTP mode. And it certainly does not help that the USB settings have been buried into the "Xperia Settings" instead of together with Wireless & Networks where other related settings are, e.g., USB tethering. Thanks a lot for your tip!

Comment: so much here and there trouble shooting, and its just this connection mode option. You saved my day

Comment: For me, it was `Settings > Storage > USB Connection Mode > (in options menu)`. Once there, I selected `MTP` and it's up and running again!

Comment: didn't work for me, i had no issue with MTP on my Previous OS, and now i have it on windows 10 and even this didn't worked out

Comment: I have no mass storage option in usb connectivity

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to check:

Is USB debugging turned on (Settings->Developer options->USB debugging)?

Is it recognised as an ADB device?  Check on Device Manager, mine is down as a Sony sa0103 ADB Interface Driver.  If not, right click on it and re install drivers.

Comment: Thanks pogba,USB debugging turned on but it's not recognised as adb device

Comment: Try opening up device manager and uninstalling what it is recognised as, then when you reinstall it, skip the first time it is recognised by the pc and it should be recognised as an ADB device the second time.

Answer (score 3):

Were you ever able to connect to your Xperia S with adb?  If not, you should try installing Sony PC Companion:

http://www.sonymobile.com/us/tools/pc-companion/

It should automatically detect your device and install the appropriate drivers.

Answer (score 3):

Installing the PC companion fixed it for me too, it changed my drivers (on windows 7 x64). I tried lots of things before, including switch to mass storage (that might have helped also).

Answer (score 2):

I have and Inew v3 phone and flashed a Sony Xperia E2115 Rom.

I'm using Android Studio to learning Android.

I use my phone to running the apps I do. But one day my phone wasn't detected on any pc I tried. With Windows 7, Ubuntu, ...

Looking for an answer, I finally found an answer:

**Settings > Apps > All > MTP extension service > Clear data/cache > Force Stop > Restart the phone**

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to update the drivers using [PC Companion](http://androidxda.com/download-sony-xperia-usb-driver). Before that I tested the following things:
1)I have the system running on Windows 8 and the problem has nothing to do with Mass Storage or MTP mode.

- In the Control Panel> Device Manager> Other devices, I found that the
  android driver was not found.
- I tried the manual installation of drivers which did not work. I
  checked the command line tool [git bash](https://msysgit.github.io/) to check if the android
  device was connected using the command adb devices. It did not show any device.

2) After the update of the device software, PC companion showed the device is up to date. I did not completely update the device where PC Companion asked for the upgrade and phone contacts have to be backed up.

3) Now when I checked the Device manager again, it shows the drivers are correctly installed.

4) adb devices in git bash show the device number and name

adb debugging works then

Answer (score 1):

I have A Sony Xperia Tipo. The drivers somehow did not work for me.
Have a look at

http://preetprasannan.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/install-adb-drivers-for-android-if-oem-drivers-not-working-not-present/

Of course you need to enable the USB Debugging in the Developer options in the Settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

Open USB debugging, and May be your usb driver is not correct ,You can use wandoujia to install the driver on your windows, here is the download page: http://www.wandoujia.com/ It can help you find the driver. Have a try

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and no matter what i did and how much I've searched the web for a solution, nothing helped! (all this of course on windows 8)

but the thing is..

i tried this procedure on windows 7, connected the device(both Sony Xperia S and Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1) then in the device manger i updated the driver then the andriod ADB interface appeared.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had terrible problems with my Xperia U and dis-ability of my PC (even the PC companion software) to see it. I tried many solutions posted on the web, nothing worked.

Finally I just switched the microUSB cable to another one I had and suddenly it works. I even uninstalled PC companion and other Sony bloatware and it is still working!

So not sure what that original microUSB cable is for (I bought my Xperia U as a second hand stuff, so not sure if in original package there are more micro USB cables), but for me it worked just for charging of the phone, no file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Xperia Connectivity -> Usb Connectivity -> Usb connection mode -> Check MTP mode.

Click Revoke USB debugging authorization in Developer option.

And try sudo adb devices.

Answer (score 0):

I tried loads of things with no joy.  Then I did a software update through the PC and it re-installed the drivers.  Now it's working again, so try this if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

**For Meizu MX5:**

Connect to PC > Pull down notifications menu > Click `Touch for other USB options` > Choose Built-in CD-ROM > The device opens on windows > Go to `F:\USB Reference Manual\EN\ADB_Reference_Manual.txt`  and follow the instructions.

For windows this is what the file says:

Create or modify the file `C:\User\<Your username>\.android\adb_usb.ini`. Add a line (with the content "0x2a45") to this file.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the USB mode isn't good enough. USB debugging must be enabled to allow adb to connect to the phone. This probably states the obvious but for me it took a while reading through these comments and wondering why adb doesn't connect. make sure your developer mode is active on the phone and "Developer Options" -> "USB debugging" is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sony Xperia Z3:

- Enable Settings > Developer options > USB debugging -> True
- Enable Settings > Device Connection > USB Connectivity -> True
- Attach Phone, Dialog "USB for transfer appears"
- opt: [Select "Mass Storage Mode (MSC)"]
- opt: [Click through "Xperia Companion Setup"]
- opt: [Software Update]
- Reboot Device and PC
- Download and unpack http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-z3-driver/
- Select "Mass Storage Mode (MTP)"
- Windows > Device Manager > Right Click on Unrecognized Device D6603 > Install new Driver: Selecto location for the unpacked xperia-z3-driver

Answer (score 0):

As nothing worked for me...

- Enable Settings > Developer options > USB debugging -> True
- Enable Settings > Device Connection > USB Connectivity -> True
- Attach Phone, Dialog "USB for transfer appears"
- opt: [Select "Mass Storage Mode (MSC)"]
- opt: [Click through "Xperia Companion Setup"]
- opt: [Software Update] Reboot Device and PC
- Maybe also then installed wrong driver.

Here is how to install the correct driver. Well, have to admit, I am new to the Sony World, and I think others might be more into it how many duplicate device types there exist.

Windows:
Now at least I found it on device manager listed under "Other devices" - for my Xperia Tablet Z it was *SGP311* of course. Just unplug and plug back in, if you are not sure, which device it is. Go back to the sony drivers page:
https://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

Or google for *Sony driver #MyDeviceId#"
Download and unzip the driver.

Now right click on the device in device manager and select "update drivers". Select drivers from local storage (automatic update was not working for me!)
Now give the folder, you just extracted/unzipped.

Now it worked for me and the device is no longer listed under "other devices". Make sure to authorize your computer for debugging on the sony device.
Just unlock the Sony Xperia and you will have to accept the prompt to pair with the computer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just had to change USB ports. For some reason this would only work on a USB 3.0 port.