# Debugging in Sony Xperia (E2003) stopped working suddenly

Tags: android, debugging, sony-xperia

My Environment:

**OS**: *Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS(Linux)*
**Android Phone**: *Sony Xperia(E2003) android version 4.4.4*
**IDE**: *Android Studio*

---

Debugging on Sony phones used to work for me, it suddenly is not working now. ***When running in debug mode the execution does not stop at break points.***. Without any change debugging works Samsung phones.

Debugging mode is enabled and I can see the device from `adb devices` command.

`adb devies` command output:
[image]

Usb debugging connection status:
[image]

The problem is weird I have many Sony Phones and all of them are not working now, so I guessed the problem is with my system but my team mates are also facing same problem.

`Logcat` is working, I see logs from user interaction.

The Debugger tab shows this message and hangs forever:

```
Connecting to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
```

---

**Update**:
I have checked the answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107545/adb-cant-detect-sony-xperia-s-although-i-installed-driver)  but my devices do not have sdcards so not working for me.

I tried to connect to the target VM manually by clicking the ff icon but the debugger gets disconnected immediately.

[image]

Following the steps [here](http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Sony-Xperia-Z1.how_to_change_the_usb_connection_options_on_my) I cant change usb connection mode. The selected option is missing on my phone. 
[image]

Comment: Is there `Connected to the target VM` log?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the drivers? Perhaps they got corrupted somehow...

Comment: Not sure but you can try Factory Reset if have many sony's devices.

Answer (score 4):

I have similar problems under Ubuntu with several devices. Usually, I just **change the USB connection mode from MTP** (*Media Transfer Mode*) **to PTP** (*Camera Mode*) to solve these kind of issues. I also suggest to change the USB cable, just to exclude extra variables.

Comment: sorry how do you change from MTP to PTP, I cant get the option.

Comment: @DegenSharew  which options do you have when you tap on the usb connection notification?

Comment: No option, but on samsung and techno phones touching the notification takes me to different screen for choosing d/t options

Comment: @DegenSharew try to reach the USB options from the Settings (not from the notification)

Comment: I went to `XperiaConnectivity -> Usb connectivity` But still I dont see any option there.

Comment: @DegenSharew As desribed here: http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Sony-Xperia-Z1.how_to_change_the_usb_connection_options_on_my  you should have some options.. I don't own this phone, I can't make a check..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94413/discussion-between-degen-sharew-and-bonnyz).

Comment: Following the steps I cant perform step 5, the option is missing. I updated my question to check the pic.

Comment: @DegenSharew Do you have an sdcard plugged on the phone? If not, try to add one and the option should appears

Comment: @dsharew were you able to figure this out? How to change to PTP ?