# Creating build in simulator settings on Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can be able to debug with android device that I have attached to PC. But when I debug with the build in emulator I get deployment error on Visual Studio and could not run. I think this error is because of I didn't have set the simulator. So, how can I set simulator settings on Visual Studio to be able to debug with `built in emulator`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug Visual Studio - Xamarin.Forms project on Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666105/how-can-i-debug-visual-studio-xamarin-forms-project-on-android-device)

Comment: @SushiHangover , thanks but I try to debud only with buid in emulator.

Comment: Which "built in emulator" that you're using? The one that comes with Android SDK (AVD) or VS Emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xamarin Android Player` has a great performance. I recommend you to install it, it should be automatically recognized by `Visual Studio`.

[Installation steps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/)

[Configuration](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/xamarin-android-player/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Xamarin's documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/) on using Emulators with Visual Studio

[This section explains configuration of device profiles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/#device_profiles).

You can check the device profiles already installed in Device Profiles Dialog

[image]

You may need to download and install new profiles if no profiles are  installed already.

[image]

After installing and configuring device profiles, you can select the emulator as below

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to run this VS emulator but there is not an option like "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" on my Visual Studio, how can I use or add this to VS? My VS is Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2. Thanks in advance