# Continuous connection/disconnection between my PC and Android phone

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, usb-drive

I am trying to build Android apps using Eclipse, I am using Sony Xperia Z3 compact to test the apps. Whenever I connect my device to the PC it keeps getting connected then disconnected continuously almost each half a second, which makes it impossible for me to run my apps on it.

I spent much time looking throw the web for a solution but unfortunately I had no luck, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053720/cannot-detect-sony-xperia-in-eclipse) they are solving the problem when the phone isn't recognized only by Eclipse, but my problem is quite different.

I also tried with Xperia Z and got the same problem. My USB debugging mode is enabled and I am using the Mass Storage mode (MSC).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: check your usb port or cable thats may hardware issue

Comment: Bad USB cable? I mean... must have though of that right?

Comment: I have three different USB cables and I tried all the ports on my PC using each one of them ... no luck

Comment: Tried on any other PC ? Your system ports may be affected

Comment: @Jibran on other PC everything works fine. How to check if there is a problem with my USB ports?

Comment: check out `Device Manager` and `Universal Serial Bus controllers`

Comment: I did. Everything looks normal!!