# Android: Running on real device

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I can't get the application to run on real device. I'm using `Eclipse`.

I followed as is said in the android developer forum but `eclipse AVD` is not finding any usb connected device. I enabled `usb debuging` in my mobile and set `android:debuggable="true"` in manifest file but Eclipse is not getting the device connected.

Comment: Few things you could try:

    On your device go to Settings > Storage > USB Computer Connection > Select Camera(PTP) mode.

    If you are using eclipse change the Base local debugger port to something like 8601. Increase the ADB connection time. Also put a check in box that says, Use ABDHOST.

Comment: Have you already installed Android USB Driver?

Comment: Which device are u using? Can u find it in the active devices in eclipse?

Comment: are you developing under linux, Mac or Windows?

Comment: read this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11974943/704374

Answer (score 0):

Did your PC recognize you phone device?In other words,did you install driver correctly?

Comment: I m using samsung mob with android 2.1 with latest driver installed, I can explore the files in my device from windows 7. I didnt find any "Camera(PTP) mode / ABDHOST". My PC recognizes phone device well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is only one point you're missing. According to http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html you have to install usb driver for adb (if you are developing on windows) or you need to add a udev rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development (if you are developing on Ubuntu Linux)

Comment: where can I get usb driver for adb for my device. Do u mean the usb driver for adb and my device IS DIFFERENT?

Answer (score 0):

Before testing your application on real device please check your device is visible in Running Devices or not.If it is not visible simply do one thing install `PdaNet` on your desktop computer it will detect driver for the respective phone and install it.You can get it [here](http://download.cnet.com/PdaNet/3000-10440_4-75059341.html)

Comment: I told that my PC detects the device well and I can explore the file in my device with windows 7 file explorer.

Comment: is your device is visible in running devices in eclipse?

Comment: If it is not visible in running devices in eclipse then install the PdaNet it automatically detects driver for the phone.Because I was also having same issue before few days and I solved it by installing PdaNet. :)

Answer (score 0):

see this url: http://creandroid.blogspot.com/2013/10/del-eclipse-un-dispositivo-android.html
 OR

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

IN thoses link is how to run aplications direct in real device