# Remote Android Chrome using adb forward is failing on Nexus 7

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb

I'm trying to set up remote web debugging for a Nexus 7 device from my Debian (well, Crunchbang) system. I can't seem to get the adb forward stage to work. The device is found, I can run logcat, etc. But when I run...

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

and then visit localhost:9222 I get "Webpage unavailable" and ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This still happens, even after restarting the adb server.

Device: Android 4.1.2 - Chrome 18.0.1025308

Desktop: Debian Squeeze. Chrome 19.0.1084.56

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when the Chrome Browser on your *android device* does not have USB web debugging turned on.

You have to enable debugging on your android device at the OS level, then again at the Chrome browser level.  Restart your adb server and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're on linux, but [this blog](http://zacktutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/08/nexus7-android-development.html) helped me a lot with Windows 7.

My point is that maybe it's deeper in your environment (i.e., linux isn't detecting the nexus 7 properly).

I know this isn't a really complete answer, but I was really frustrated too and this fixed it.

I got the answer from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974700/nexus-7-not-visible-over-usb-via-adb-devices-from-windows-7-x64).