# Cant connect Sony Xperia L C2104 to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, sony-xperia

I have Sony Xperia L (C2104) and I want to connect it to Eclipse (Juno) for testing and debugging Android Apps. I have installed the Sony's PC companion software. I have turned on the USB Debugging via 'Developer Options' and the USB Connection Mode is MTP.

When I plug my device to Laptop, running Windows 8, the notification bar shows 'USB Debugging Connected' and 'Internal Storage & SD Card Connected'. However, when I start Eclipse, It does not show my device in 'Android Device Chooser' window..

I think the device drivers should have got installed along with the PC Companion Software but When I right click on My Computer -> Manage -> Devices, It shows a device 'Android' in Other Devices category along with a '!' with it. So maybe the drivers are absent.

Please help, need to test app on it urgently. I Searched drivers for Xperia L on Sony's website http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/ but couldn't find the driver.

Comment: Once restart your Eclipse ide or Reset the adb (In Eclipse -> Devices-> click the dropdown)

Comment: hey try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/11974943/704374 this will surely solve your problem.

Comment: You should be able to use the standard usb driver for that through standard drivers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974700/nexus-7-not-visible-over-usb-via-adb-devices-from-windows-7-x64/14083512#14083512

Comment: Aerrow, Where is the Devices option in Eclipse ?

Comment: Sumit Bisht, I directed the path in Drivers Wizard to '<sdk>/extras\google' but it didn't find any drivers there..

Comment: @tigerden I've xperia L too. Are you fixed that problem ?

Comment: Yup...I downloaded Sony PC Companion from Sony's website and installed it. That came with appropriate drivers

Answer (score 4):

This works for me . I changed the following setting in the phone.
Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > USB connection mode
and select Mass storage mode (MSC).
By default Media transfer mode (MTP) is selected and USB cable must be unplugged to change this option.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread still I am adding few details from [Sony official website](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/) there is a read me provided. It says `If you can’t find the driver you are looking for, drivers for all Sony smartphones and tablets are available in our PC Companion software.`

So for making this work you need to download PC companion software form this [link](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/). After installing the software you will be able to download the driver for your phone.

Comment: Thanks worked for me!!  Also after installing PC companion software i have to update the software. Just click start on first box.

Answer (score 2):

You need an adb driver, not just their standard driver (sometimes they are the same, but often they are not).

For a list of adb drivers, follow this link [ADB driver listing](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Here's a [Sony specific list](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/)

Answer (score 2):

At times for sony experia the developer options are hidden. To unlock it do the following.

You have to go to settings-> About Phone -> build version.

Click on build version 7 times to unlock the developer options. I tried this and it worked perfectly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's late to answer this question, but I had the same problem just now and solved it

Install the universal ADB driver from http://adbdriver.com/upload/AdbDriverInstaller.exe
(you might have to change between Media Transfer mode and Mass storage mode on your phone, they use different driver)

On eclipse, Open Perspective > ddms
There's a devices panel that opens up. There's a small white triangle on the right, click on it and click reset adb [image: devices, reset adb]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Worked for me installing PdaNet driver downloaded from http://www.junefabrics.com/android/download.php

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Sony PC Companion from Sony's website and installed it. That came with appropriate drivers..

Answer (score 0):

I did the same trick that Akash has posted
"*At times for sony experia the developer options are hidden. To unlock it do the following.
You have to go to settings-> About Phone -> build version.
Click on build version 7 times to unlock the developer options. I tried this and it worked perfectly.
Hope it helps.*"
It also worked for my sony  Xperia L C2104