# Nexus 7 does not show under 'adb devices' with Windows 8 PC

Tags: android, adb, nexus-7

I have done this in the past a few times, I see this process has changed a little.

Yes, I have already:

- Installed Android Studio
- Changed the `USB computer connection` to the NOT-very-straight-forward option `Camera (PTP)`.
- I have tapped the `Build number` found under `Settings->About tablet` 7 times in anxiety until I "became a developer" and the good old `{} Developer options` gracefully appeared again under `Settings->System` section.
- Inside `Settings->Developer options` I have upper `Developer options` switched ON, and `USB debugging` as well.
- On Android Studio, `Tools->Android->SDK Manager` I have installed Google USB Driver rev 1.0
- Made sure both USB cable and ports and Nexus 7 are working and %100 functional. (I can copy the pictures from the device to the PC just fine)

**EDIT**: Where are the Nexus 7 (2013) drivers for Windows 8.1 available at?

What did I miss? Besides the fact I want to to get this done, I'm also partly posting this question so other developers who want to test on their 2nd generation Nexus 7 with Android KitKat 4.4.3 would have 1 complete thread with all of the instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974700/nexus-7-not-visible-over-usb-via-adb-devices-from-windows-7-x64) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-nexus-7) because this isn't as straight forward anymore in my opinion.

Comment: Did you... Download the latest driver? Change USB port? Change USB cable?

Comment: to whom who saw this question worthy of a down vote: can you explain yourself?

Comment: I don't know, it is very straight forward in my opinion. You just need to download the usb drivers in the sdk manager and then connect your device. You may also need to select said usb drivers for the device. But aside from that it is pretty much plug & play. Especially on a Mac. There you don't need drivers at all. Just connect and you are ready to go. Mostly if it isn't working it's either a problem with the device (for example usb debugging is not enabled) or a broken cable or the drivers are not installed.

Comment: It's being downvoted because this question has been asked a thousand times before.

Comment: @ScottBarta can you give a reference to a duplicate with a solution?

Comment: You need to download the google usb drivers. inside eclipse go to window - android sdk manager- go to the bottom of the list and download the USB drivers. unplug your device and plug it in again. it should be recognized

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have finally figured this one out:

[This guide](http://droider.eu/2013/10/10/adb-cant-find-your-new-nexus-7-2nd-gen/) tells you to go and get the [Google USB Driver from google](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top).

For me, Downloading it as an optional SDK component just didn't do the trick. But [on the very same page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#WinUsbDriver), there's a button that says `Download Google USB Driver` (near upper left corner, in blue.) This gets you `latest_usb_driver_windows.zip` file.

Use [this guide right here](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-7-2013-drivers-installation-guide/) If you are unsure how to install this driver. I could see my Nexus on adb after I've done this. Best of luck!

Comment: Somehow the SDK manager didn't produce the goods but following the manual path did.  Been at this for hours - thank you my friend.

Comment: This was a key thing to do as we!! Thanks, I will upvote you and post a complete list including Developer and PTP.

Comment: Yes, I had to install it manually too... Thank you, Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks, the guide on the bottom of this answer helped me, by following the "TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS!"

Comment: Installing the USB driver from SDK manager did not work. Manually downloaded and installed the 64bit verison, then it worked. I think there is a problem in the SDK manager under 64bit Windows.