# Eclipse - Unable to detect my Xperia U

Tags: android, eclipse, sony-xperia

Well I've been trying to make Eclipse and the Android SDK recognize my Xperia U for a couple hours now, but no progress so far.

The phone is detected by my computer and USB debugging is turned on. I've tried manually installing Sony's USB driver but it did not change anything as far as I can tell.

I don't really know what to do now.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Download the correct driver for your phone, make sure your phone has enabled USB debugging and then connect it to proceed with the install.Download drivers from:http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/ and follow the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974700/nexus-7-not-visible-over-usb-via-adb-devices-from-windows-7-x64/14083512#14083512)to update the drivers

Comment: Like I said, I already did that. But for some reason, I do not see any option to change the USB mode...

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the second link provided