# Nexus 7 tablet won't enter debugging mode on visual studio for MAC xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

what can I do to get my tablet to enter debugging mode when I connect to my macbook pro.

it was fine two days ago, but now when I connect it, it only charges and I can't get it to enter debugging mode so I can run my app that I am developing on it.

Yes its in debugging mode in the developer setttings.

I have tried using terminal to try and set it up via wifi, but the commands "abd" dont work.

Ideally I want it just to go back to working via usb. What can I do as the emulator I use is so slow. ?

Comment: If you are using android studio parallel please quit your android studio and try again.

Comment: If you go into `Developer options` on the tablet and `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` and then connect it via USB, do you get prompted with a "Allow UDB debugging" dialog?

Comment: its visual studio, community. for MAC......

Comment: @SushiHangover no I tryed that also doesnt do anything

Comment: @james.d_12 Does the `Android File Transfer` utility work? Just wondering if you have a bad cable ;-)

Comment: no just charges

Answer (score 0):

When the Nexus 7 is plugged in there is a persistent notification that indicates "CONNECT AS / Media Device (MTP)"

[Check this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974700/nexus-7-not-visible-over-usb-via-adb-devices-from-windows-7-x64?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: that does not come up either. AS i stated, it worked fine two days ago. I know what is and isnt supposed to do, but now it only charges, nothing else happens. no notifications, no alerts, nothing.

Comment: Check your cable and usb port.